# Buscar en ListView Kotlin

Tags: listview, kotlin, edittext

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el que obtenido mi lista de contactos  y se los he pasado a una listview. Pero necesito filtrar los contactos mediante un edittext y no encuentro ninguna solución por ningún sitio. Espero que alguien me ayude, os paso a continuación el código. Gracias.

Custom Adapter:

```
class ContactsAdapter(private val context: Context, private val 
contactModelArrayList: ArrayList<ContactModel>) : BaseAdapter() {

override fun getViewTypeCount(): Int {
    return count
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {

    return position
}

override fun getCount(): Int {
    return contactModelArrayList.size
}

override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
    return contactModelArrayList[position]
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return 0
}

override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    var convertView = convertView
    val holder: ViewHolder

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = ViewHolder()
        val inflater = context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts, null, true)

        holder.tvname = convertView!!.findViewById(R.id.name) as TextView


        convertView.tag = holder
    } else {
        // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
        holder = convertView.tag as ViewHolder
    }

    holder.tvname!!.setText(contactModelArrayList[position].getNames())


    return convertView
}

private inner class ViewHolder {

    var tvname: TextView? = null


}

}
```

ContactModel:

```
class ContactModel {

var name: String? = null


fun setNames(name: String) {
    this.name = name
}

fun getNames(): String {
    return name.toString()
}

}
```

Main Class:

```
class RecentsSearch : AppCompatActivity() {
private var listView: ListView? = null
private var customAdapter: ContactsAdapter? = null
private var contactModelArrayList: ArrayList<ContactModel>? = null
private var et_search : EditText? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recents_search)

    listView= findViewById(R.id.listViewSearch) as ListView
    et_search= findViewById(R.id.searchText) as EditText
    contactModelArrayList = ArrayList()

    val phones = 
contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.
CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, 
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC")
    while (phones!!.moveToNext()) {
        val name =  
phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.
CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME))
        val contactModel = ContactModel()
        contactModel.setNames(name)
        contactModelArrayList!!.add(contactModel)
    }
    phones.close()

    customAdapter = ContactsAdapter(this, contactModelArrayList!!)
    listView!!.adapter = customAdapter

    et_search!!.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            listView!!.setFilterText(s.toString())
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, 
count: Int, after: Int) {
            listView!!.setFilterText(s.toString())            }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, 
before: Int, count: Int) {
                      }

    })
}
}
```

activity.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RecentsSearch"
android:background="@drawable/fondo_gradient">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logosm"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.03"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/presence_online"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchText"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.1"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorTurquoise"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/magnifier"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.112"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.16"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_close"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.119"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.83"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.19"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
    android:src="@drawable/contacts"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.218"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.456"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTurquoise"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.31"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_group"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="Create group"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTurquoise"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="370dp"
    android:id="@+id/listViewSearch"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:elevation="100dp"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

contacts.xml

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/contact_background_selector"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/contacts"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="Name"/>

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Cuando usamos un editText, el usuario puede escribir un parámetro de búsqueda y nosotros comparamos ese resultado con las palabras de la lista, que no es más que un ArrayList, por lo que yo haría un método en el que pasas el string del usuario y lo que te devuelve es un nuevo arraylist con las coincidencias, y eso se lo pasas al adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando usamos un `editText`, el usuario puede escribir un parámetro de búsqueda y nosotros comparamos ese resultado con las palabras de la lista, que no es más que un `ArrayList`, por lo que yo haría un método en el que pasas el string del usuario y lo que te devuelve es un nuevo `arraylist` con las coincidencias, y eso se lo pasas al adapter.

Te dejo un ejemplo muy sencillo en Kotlin que hay que adaptar a tus necesidades, como pueden ser los parámetros de la función:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val wordToSearch = "example1"
        val possibleResults: List<String> = listOf("example1", "example2", "example3", "example4")

        getUserCoincidence(wordToSearch, possibleResults).forEach {
            Log.i("test", it)
        }
    }

    private fun getUserCoincidence(wordToSearch: String, possibleResults: List<String>): List<String>
            = possibleResults.filter { it == wordToSearch }
}
```

El método `getUserCoincidence()` te devuelve una `List<String>` con las coincidencias, esa lista se la pasas al adapter.  En el ejemplo puedes comprobar que el log saca por pantalla las coincidencias que van a aparecer en tu lista.

Comment: por favor añade un ejemplo, para que tu respuesta se considere de mejor calidad

Answer (score 0):

En esta lambda el tercer parámetro indica la posición del item seleccionado del ListView. Con este valor podemos ubicar en el arreglo de habitantes el valor respectivo.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val paises = arrayOf( "Argentina", "Chile", "Paraguay", "Bolivia", "Peru", "Ecuador", "Brasil", "Colombia", "Venezuela", "Uruguay")
    var habitantes = arrayOf(40_000_000, 17_000_000, 6_500_000, 10_000_000, 30_000_000, 14_000_000, 183_000_000, 44_000_000, 31_000_000, 3_500_000)
    val adaptador1 = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, paises)
    list1.adapter = adaptador1
    list1.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, i, l ->
        tv1.text = "Población de: ${habitantes[i]}"
    }
}
```